# Breakpoint after Thread.join()

Tags: android, multithreading, debugging

I am debugging my Android Application, and I run into trouble when I want to set a breakpoint after I joined a thread.

```
ImageSaverThread ist = new ImageSaverThread(mPreview.getmCameraInstance());
ist.start();
File file1 = ist.getOutputMediaFile(1);
try {
    ist.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("IST ERROR", "ImageSaverThread did not finish!");
    return;
}
File mediaStorageDir = new File(String.valueOf(
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)));
File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    "IMG_" + "TEST" + ".jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(file));
```

When I set a breakpoint to the last line of code, my image that I save through `ImageSaverThread` is not yet saved, because the join does not work in debugger.

I already selected the breakpoint and told it only to suspend this thread, not all, but still, it does not work. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: "I run into trouble when I want to set a breakpoint after I joined a thread" the best advice is "don't do that".  Breakpoint debuggers are just about never necessary - they are a luxury, and using one is not always simply about clicking a button.  Sometimes you have to think creatively.  There are near countless other ways of investigating whatever your actual programming problem is.

Comment: well, or I just skip the .join(), tell the thread to sleep for 1 second instead, and then i can debug. that solved the issue for me.

Comment: The point is you don't *need* to run your app under the debugger to begin with.  Unless you are willing to box yourself into a narrow range of technologies, you will not always have one available, and learning how to approach a problem by other means is a key skill that can prove very helpful even where one is available.

Comment: I know what you mean. For me it was important to take a closer look at the Bitmap object to understand how it works and what it is composed of.

Comment: You should be able to see that in the documentation, or even the code completion of your editor...